# lot numbering without caption

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, numbering, include

I am trying to import on my document several tables in png format that where created with excel. They already include the caption and the table number so I don't want to include a caption. Following advises given here and there I use the following command:

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\stepcounter{table}
\includegraphics{mytable.png}
\addcontentsline{lot}{section}{\protect\numberline\thetable\ignorespaces mytable title}
\end{table}
```

That way I can import my table and have it listed in the `LoT` with the correct number. This works perfectly until table 9. For table 10, the list of table splits the 1 and the 0: the 1 is place at the right place but the 0 ends up with the table title.

What I am doing wrong here?

Thanks so much for your help

Best

Answer (score 2):

`\numberline` has an argument which should be used with a pair of braces: `{...}`,
otherwise `\thetable` will be expanded and from 10,.... `\numberline` sees the leading figure first, i.e. `1`, but not the following ones (`0`,`1`,etc.) -- those will be treated as being part of the title:

(the `\foreach` loop is only for demo purposes)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}

\listoftables


\setcounter{table}{9}%
\foreach \x in {10,...,20} {%
\begin{table}
\centering
\stepcounter{table}
%\includegraphics{mytable.png}
\addcontentsline{lot}{section}{\protect\numberline\thetable\ -- wrong usage}
\addcontentsline{lot}{section}{\protect\numberline{\thetable} -- mytable title}
\end{table}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]